# Building my first Azure functions , am i doing things correctly?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created my first Azure Function which integrate with SharePoint Online list, using those main points:-

1-I created an Azure App with self-sign certificate to authorize my Azure function.

[image]

2-I created a new Azure Function project using Visual Studio 2019. here are the main components `Function.cs`:-

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public  class Function1
        
    {
        private readonly IPnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory;
        public Function1(IPnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory)
        {
            this.pnpContextFactory = pnpContextFactory;
        
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            using (var context = pnpContextFactory.Create("Default"))
            {
                var myList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SubFolders");
                Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Title", System.DateTime.Now }
    };

                // Use the AddBatch method to add the request to the current batch
                myList.Items.AddBatch(values);
                context.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:-

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp1.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    class Startup :FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
            var azureFunctionSettings = new AzureFunctionSettings();
            config.Bind(azureFunctionSettings);
            builder.Services.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.DisableTelemetry = true;
                var authProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(azureFunctionSettings.ClientId,
                    azureFunctionSettings.TenantId,
                    StoreName.My,
                    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                    azureFunctionSettings.CertificateThumbprint);
                options.DefaultAuthenticationProvider = authProvider;

                options.Sites.Add("Default", new PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration.PnPCoreSiteOptions

                {
                    SiteUrl = azureFunctionSettings.SiteUrl,
                    AuthenticationProvider = authProvider


                });

            });
        
        }

    }
}
```

`local.setting.json`:-

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "SiteUrl": "https://***.sharepoint.com/",
    "TenantId": "0b***",
    "ClientId": "92***",
    "CertificateThumbPrint": "EB***",
    "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES": "EB***"
  }
}
```

then i deploy it to Azure and it is working well, where each 5 minutes it adds a new list item. but i have those questions:-

1. Am i am doing things correctly, especially from a security perspective? as at the end my Azure function will have a public URL as follow `https://functionapp1*****.azurewebsites.net` and this can be called by any anonymous user.. so is this a security hole? if so, then how i can fix it?
2. I am currently using self-Signed certificate, so is it fine for Production? if not, then what i need to do , to get a proper SSL ?

Thanks

**EDIT**. Here is the url for the fucntion

[image]

Comment: your function is using time trigger. There's no endpoints exposed

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes i know , but when i access the function inside Azure, i get that it has a url, chekc my edit i uploaded a screen shot. thanks

Comment: Did you open that link in an incognito window? What did you see?

Comment: @IdusOrtus i will get a web page with this text `Your Functions 3.0 app is up and running
Azure Functions is an event-based serverless compute experience to accelerate your development.`

Comment: @johnGu Yep! That's all the external access your example provides. Since you're not exposing any endpoints or accepting external input, you should be fine. You might want to consider v4 functions but, for your example, it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @IdusOrtus ok i see thanks, so there is no way to secure this access,, i mean i do not want anonymous user to know that i have a Timer Trigger Function, why to expose this info even

Comment: @johnGu Google: 'azure function disable default page' . We have numerous Azure Functions deployed for production and I have never used this feature. Looks like what you want though. Thanks for the learning opportunity.